# JQuery cleaning my page view after I add some html links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

- What i want

When I try to accomplish this exercise on this [link](http://exercices.openclassrooms.com/assessment/534?login=6463957&tk=ae61f26683862339a1de1be6303a6298&sbd=2016-02-01&sbdtk=2466d6bae51e373d89ac8e3f74213199). when i try to add a link by submitting my form.

I should get another link displayed in the main list, but it does something ,then restarts to the old display.

- What i tried and found

I checked in the debugger what is happening, and it seems that after this part of Jquery code executed, all the page gets cleaned.

```
if ( !( eventHandle = elemData.handle ) ) {
            eventHandle = elemData.handle = function( e ) {

                // Discard the second event of a jQuery.event.trigger() and
                // when an event is called after a page has unloaded
                return typeof jQuery !== "undefined" && jQuery.event.triggered !== e.type ?
                    jQuery.event.dispatch.apply( elem, arguments ) : undefined;
            };
        }
```

You can find my code on this jsfiddle link :  JSfiddle introduce an error related to JS; to see the "clean" you should directly test in the browser. https://jsfiddle.net/didiercas/hvham7by/

Comment: The link[1] = [1]: http://exercices.openclassrooms.com/assessment/534?login=6463957&tk=ae61f26683862339a1de1be6303a6298&sbd=2016-02-01&sbdtk=2466d6bae51e373d89ac8e3f74213199

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need to do a preventDefault on click of the button.

Comment: Yes, it solved my issue ! But this looks a little bit of magic for me what has happened actually ? What behaviour did i prevent to do happen by adding 
`event.preventDefault();`

Comment: I check which event was being prevented by adding `console.log(event.type)` before and after `event.preventDefault();` 
and the event type is called : `preventClick`.

Comment: you're preventing the default behavior of a click on a link/button, the default behavior is to go the the resource pointed by the link thus a reload will happen in browser due to which you don't see your newly added things.